# See All Server Bot in

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I don't know how to do this, but I want to make like if i say !list and bot will show all the server my bot in and then i want to do like !invite (server name) and bot will make an invite link and send to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```js
let guilds = '';
   <client>.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
      guilds = guilds.concat(guild).concat("\n"); // Adds a new line after each guild
   });

console.log(guilds);
```

And of course you can adjust / format this for your needs :)